# Google Ad Manager - Failed to load ad by using unit id (ERROR - "ad failed to load 1")

Tags: java, android, google-ad-manager

I have created ad unit id for native ad style in ad manager, when I m trying to load my ad in the android app it's not loading ads and it shows "ad failed to load 1".
But when I used google test ad unit id it's working properly and all ads are loaded
I have created an ad unit id using https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/177203?hl=en

Comment: What ad unit ID are you using?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you set your payment method in google admob from payment setting page

Answer (score 0):

You cant see your ads instantly. You have to wait couple of days to see your actual ads. Dont forget to add your test devices Ids (You can find from console logs). If you dont you will be suspended if you click your real ads.